# Call into 64bit Dephi DLL from C# on 64bit Machine

Tags: c#, delphi, winapi, 64-bit

I my c# app I am trying to call into a Delphi DLL build as 64bit.  I keep getting an error stating "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B".  I am running on a Windows 7 64 bit machine and have my C# project set to Any CPU.

API call

```
[DllImport("Cipher.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
public static extern void Encrypt(StringBuilder szPlainText, StringBuilder  zCipherText);

Encrypt(plainString, encText);
```

If the Delphi DLL was build as 32bit this call works fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: `ThisCall` is wrong. Delphi doesn't do that. Use `stdcall`.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason your app is not run as a 64-bit but rather a 32-bit process. If you need to do things like this, it's better to specify "x64" instead of "AnyCPU".

Comment: If there are any doubts, ProcessMonitor (SysInternals.com) will verify whether the host process is running as 64 or 32.

Comment: If the app is 32-bit, then there probably is not a good reason to make a 64-bit DLL. It sounds cool, that's about it. Unless you've got a 64-bit app, or are building a shell extension DLL, there is no need for 64 just because the OS is 64-bit.

Comment: (or generalized: plugin into something 64-bit, OS, IE or third party)